# Restore processes instances from database. JBPM6

Tags: database, jboss, persistence, drools, jbpm

I succesfully connected jbpm to my database (PostgreSQL) and i store logs into it. I made it by:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();  
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();  
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("WorkflowSession");  
EntityManagerFactory emf = new EnvironmentProducer().getEntityManagerFactory();  
AbstractAuditLogger auditLogger = AuditLoggerFactory.newJPAInstance(emf);  
kSession.addEventListener(auditLogger);
```

I would like to restore all active processes after server falling. For example:

1. Start scenario (start process)
2. Server fall down (the process is in database register as active)
3. After turn on server again have this process loaded to my new KieSession

Please help me with this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to reload process instances after server shutdown.  Process instances are always stored in the database, and whenever they are needed, they are loaded from there.  This includes user requests related to the process instance (e.g. tasks completed, signals sent), but also timers firing etc.

The only thing you should try to do upon initialization of the application in case you embed the engine yourself is to make sure the runtime manager is instantiated (for keeping track of timers).  If you use the execution server (part of the jbpm-console), it will automatically do that for you.

Comment: Kris, could you show the example of this execution server? The example with code is highly appreciated!